# What does "trail" mean in "trail of death"?

Tags: meaning

I read this sentence saying:

> The wildfires leave trail of death in California.

What does the word "trail" mean here? The closest meaning I found in dictionary is "marks by actions". So, is it like "The fires lead to the result of death in CA"?

Thanks

Comment: Try a different dictionary.  Most dictionaries give example usages, and I’d be very surprised if one didn’t have an example of something like “left a ~ of ...”

Comment: It did work... Thanks! I used the app dictionary. It's kind of confusing. Now it's clear! It means a long path as it moves. (Very useful! )

Answer (score 1):

As fire moves along the ground, it leaves a trail behind it. The trail consists of burned plants and animals.